# Webdriver Javascript how to click a download button in a modal

Tags: node.js, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I'm trying to build a node.js script that runs with chromedriver and selenium-webdriver: logs into a website, navigates to a download section and clicks a download button.

The website is twitter, and the data is campaign data that is in a csv file.

I've hacked this together so my code won't be perfect or great.

I am basically at the last point where I need to click a downloadButton with the following 'Inspect Element' data:

```
<button id="downloadButton" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
```

I cannot locate this html in the page source, only via 'Inspect Element' (Using chrome)

main.js:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
build();

username = "username"
password = "password"

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000);

// Navigate to Twitter ads login page //
driver.get('https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=https%3A%2F%2Fads.twitter.com%2F');

// Enters a username into the username box //
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//form[@class=\"t1-form clearfix signin js-signin\"]//input[@name=\"session[username_or_email]\"]")).sendKeys(username);

// Enters a password into a password box //
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//form[@class=\"t1-form clearfix signin js-signin\"]//input[@name=\"session[password]\"]")).sendKeys(password);

//Clicks the sign in button
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//form[@class=\"t1-form clearfix signin js-signin\"]//button[@class=\"submit btn primary-btn\"]")).click()

//Clicks the campaign of choice //
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//form[@id=\"account-selector-form\"]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/img")).click();

// Selects the calendar // 
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//div//*[@id=\"dashboardBox\"]/form/div/div/span[2]")).click();

//Click on year of data //
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//div[7]/div[4]/ul/li[6]")).click();

//Clicks the export button // 
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//div//*[@id=\"dashboard-header\"]/div/div/div/button/span")).click();

//This bit doesnt work: //
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("downloadButton")).click()
```

packages.json:

```
{
  "name": "webdriver-recipes",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "selenium-webdriver": "~2.42.1"
  }
}
```

Thanks for the assist.

Comment: can you share the url of the website ?

Comment: the url is in the code, its: https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=https%3A%2F%2Fads.twitter.com%2F